# Href's on /ask question (and others) while on the page that it links to

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

Noticed that I was unable to open a new instance of "/ask question" (in a new tab) when I was in the midst of asking one question, and thought of another I wanted to create at least the title for.

Can also see coding href's into this menu bar, even for pages that one is currently on, as being advantageous for manually refreshing the page (Yes, there is always the browser refresh controls).

Is this something that the community thinks is worthwhile to change/can be done?

Answer (score 7):

I posted this exact question [years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61666/cant-click-ask-question-when-on-the-ask-a-question-page), for the same reason. It's intentionally disabled because apparently some very confused people think that after they've filled out the question form, they should click the "ask question" link again to post, and get mad when instead it takes them to a blank ask question page. This only happens on the ask question page; the others are always linked even if you're already on that page

Comment: LOL. "OMG" Thanks Michael Mrozek! I have +2'd you, for the relatively more time you invested illustrating this point, and +1'd [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61666/cant-click-ask-question-when-on-the-ask-a-question-page#comment146968_61673) very good point!!